# PDF magazine with pageflip effect

Tags: flash, pdf, flip

Hi
I'm looking for an extension/softwre to display PDF magazine with pageflip effect. It is not a problem to create flipping magazine with images. What about PDF?

I don't see any extension/software worth of respect... Could you help?

Answer (score 3):

Flash can only load images (jpegs) and cannot render PDF, you will need to convert the pages to images (manually or automatically) and display the images through your own UI via flash.

You could use something like GhostScript to rasterize the PDF to jpegs.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but I think it's worth answering as it's one of the first results in google.

You can try with http://heyzine.com it can convert the pdf to a magazine with a good page flip effect. It allows you to download the magazine, hot link or use it as a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pageflip built into the JPedal PDF viewer (see screenshot on front page at http://www.jpedal.org).

Comment: sorry, I think lillian's recommendation, "axmag.com", has better pageflip effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create transitions within the PDF itself.  I don't know what you're using to build your PDFs, so it's hard to know if that particular tool supports setting page transitions.

```
<</Type/Page /Trans <</S/Wipe>> ... >>
```

That specifies a wipe transition from left to right (the default), that takes one second (default again).

If you're looking for something fancier than that, you'll have to look outside the bounds of PDF technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something like below (with page curl effect), than you can make use of many online converters, for example http://pressmo.com

[image: flip book example]

Comment: ...and video tutorial about Pressmo...how to work
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwV4qXbqauk